# Persistently caching DNS cache for Linux

Tags: dns

Is there a free DNS proxy/cache software that caches positive answers indefinitely until some new positive answer is received ? That means the cache should live longer than the TTL received as long as the upstream DNS server does not answer or gives a negative (NXDOMAIN) answer.

An alternative name for this question could have been **Resilient DNS cache** as it helps in case of outages.

Best cache behavior would be not to forward client queries if a cached answer is available within its TTL and forward client queries otherwise. If there is no answer within a configurable timeout or there is a negative answer from upstream, the cache contents are returned with some configurable artificial TTL value. If there is a positive answer, it is returned to the client and saved in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, the term you're looking for is **"serve stale" or "serve expired".** Quite a few DNS resolvers support serving old data; this feature actually exists even as an [IETF specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8767.html).

For example,

- "serve-stale" has been implemented by [ISC BIND 9.11](https://www.isc.org/blogs/2020-serve-stale/) (the link is to a blog post which also talks about the history of the feature);
- it is called "serve-expired" in [Unbound](https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/) – might go along well with its "prefetch" feature (which automatically refreshes cached entries);
- [dnsdist](https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/issues/7239) has had "keepStaleData" added in 1.4.0;
- while [pdns-recursor](https://mailman.powerdns.com/pipermail/pdns-users/2016-November/024549.html) still has only a pending feature request.

However, this only works for complete outages. It **does not** apply to NXDOMAIN responses, as those are still perfectly *valid* responses – a fake "no such domain" is indistinguishable from a legitimate one (unless it fails DNSSEC vallidation). Negative replies are in fact cacheable too.

---

Additionally, many resolvers support putting a minimum limit on the received TTL, so that e.g. replies with a TTL of 30 seconds would instead be cached for 5 minutes. This can help when using an unreliable upstream resolver.

- Unbound has "cache-min-ttl";
- dnsmasq has "min-cache-ttl" (limited to 1 hour).

---

Similar threads:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/817589/can-a-local-dns-cache-be-configured-to-use-stale-records-when-upstream-fails
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287836/how-to-override-ttl-in-a-caching-only-bind9